# Gnome 3 - Gedit 3.10 Any Auto session saver plugin?

Tags: 13.10, gedit, session

I am on Ubuntu 13.10 Gnome shell 3.10.I want to automatically restore tabs in gedit that were open in previous session (without any manual work) - Just like a web browser - FF/Chrome.

Any such compatible plugin ?

Comment: By defaut there is only last files option. But may be there is some plugin for this. Never seen such plugin but its one of things that can help to the most of gedit users. Its really bad when something crashes and you understand that now you must open all those tabs again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Gedit 3.10 (included in Ubuntu 14.04 too) you can use [gedit-restore-tabs](https://github.com/raelgc/gedit-restore-tabs):

> Upon starting Gedit, this plugin will try restore all open documents from the last Gedit window that was closed.

For older versions, you might want to try the [reopen-tabs-gedit-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/reopen-tabs-gedit-plugin/):

> The plugin is intended to be used by those who uses gedit as a source code editor. It spares you reopening the documents that were loaded last time you closed gedit.

Comment: Does it work for gedit 3.10 ? Its not working for me.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated my answer with a link to a plugin that does the same thing but works with Gedit 3.

Comment: It works for gedit3 (<=3.8) . But for 13.10 its not working :(

Comment: @mac, try this fix (it worked for me on 14.04): https://github.com/Quixotix/gedit-restore-tabs/issues/12

Comment: No need to apply any fix if we use raelgc repo (the link provided in answer)

Comment: https://github.com/disfated/gedit-plugin-reopen-tabs works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for the latest version check out https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-restore-tabs/tree/gedit3.8

He has updated it to use python3 and a couple other fixes